# How to set DNS exclusively for a Network Namespace

Tags: networking, dns, resolv.conf

I've created a network namespace. I thought there was a `resolv.conf` file for each namespaces created but it's not the case on my system (Ubuntu 14.04). I don't have the following path `/etc/netns/namespace_name/resolv.conf`.. The folder `netns` doesn't exist.

There is only one `resolv.conf` (`/etc/resolv.conf` and another one mirrored in `/run/resolv.conf`). Any changes in this file affect all network interfaces. Is there a way I can use different DNS for both the host and the namespace?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

(Solution found on ServerFault)

Create the directory `/etc/netns/NAMESPACENAME` and place the different version of the `resolv.conf` file there.

Comment: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ip-netns.8.html  This seems to be a per application issue and only applies to applications aware of the network name-spacing.

Comment: Not really.  The same page says it later (could have been phrased better, though): `ip netns exec automates handling of this configuration, file  convention for network namespace unaware applications, by creating a mount namespace and bind mounting all of the per network namespace configure files into their traditional location in /etc.`  So you need to create /etc/netns/<netns_name>/resolv.conf, and ip netns will automatically mount-bind it to /ets/resolv.conf. So any application that will lookup /etc/resolv.conf from *within* the network namespace, will actually look at its own resolv.conf.